# I want atleast 1 checkbox is select but not more than 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple checkboxes in my form creating dynamically.I want that atleast one checkbox is checked but limit to check is 3 also.User cannot check more than 3.Plz help me

Comment: Please provide what you have done so far.

Comment: Share your html code

Comment: <label><input type="checkbox" onclick='chkcontrol(<?php echo $x ?>)' name="ckb" value="<?php echo $r[1];?>"><?php echo $r[1];?></label>

unction chkcontrol(j) {
var total=0;
for(var i=0; i < document.form1.ckb.length; i++){
if(document.form1.ckb[i].checked){
total =total +1;}
if(total > 3){
alert("You can select only three Service providers..!") 
document.form1.ckb[j].checked = false ;
return false;
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Should be probably something like that:

```
var checked = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

if (checked == 0) {
  //nothing checked
}
else if (checked < 3) {
  //ok
}
else {
  //too many checked
}
```

You might want to add class or parent selector to get only right checkboxes.

EDIT: To run after clicking button:

```
function service_prov_choose() {
  var checked = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

  if (checked == 0) {
    //nothing checked
  }
  else if (checked < 3) {
    //ok
  }
  else {
    //too many checked
  }
}
```

Comment: i put alert in yr code bt it displays on page load.I want this code to be run when user clicks submit.
Here is my submit code
<input type="button" name="ubmit" class="btn-primary" value="Submit" onclick="service_prov_choose()"/>

plz help